# How can I remove ":" from a string in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How can I get rid of ":" from my string in a batch file?

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,6,7 skip=6 delims= " %%f in (%FILE_LIST%) do (
java -jar D:\HDLdi2.3.9\lib\oracle.ucm.fa_client_11.1.1.jar DownloadTool --dID=%%f --url=%UCM_Link% --username=%_UserName% --password=%_Password% "--outputfile=E:\FusionData\Outbound\%PROPERTY%\Temp\%FILE_NAME%_%%i_%%j.txt"
)
```

I got the error message because I have %%i as 2018-01-23 and %%j as 13:12:11Z and %%j have ":" in my output file extension.

Sorry for misleading for the first question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Based upon your comment, _(the one which ignored my quickest reply)_, you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48409147/edit) to include the real code, _i.e. the `For /F` loop_.

Comment: Please read [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this:

```bat
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Skip=6 Tokens=1,2,3,6,7 Delims= " %%f In (%FILE_LIST%) Do (
    Set "FFNAME=%%i_%%j"
    Set "FFNAME=!FFNAME:-=!"
    Set "FFNAME=!FFNAME::=!"
    Set "FFNAME=!FFNAME:~,15!"
    java -jar D:\HDLdi2.3.9\lib\oracle.ucm.fa_client_11.1.1.jar DownloadTool --dID=%%f --url=%UCM_Link% --username=%_UserName% --password=%_Password% "--outputfile=E:\FusionData\Outbound\%PROPERTY%\Temp\%FILE_NAME%_!FFNAME!.txt"
)
```

Comment: I have updated my post to help you specifically with the problem you indicated in your question(s). _The code does not take account of any issues, syntax or otherwise, outside of the scope of setting a variable based upon your variables `%%i` and `%%j` and supplementing it to your `java` command as is._

Comment: So great help. Thank you so much! Could you please tell me what's the difference between %Variable% and !Variable!? Thanks!

Comment: The clue lies in the first line of my answer!

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation in batch isn't particularly complicated, if a bit unintuitive. The way this can be handled is `%<variable>:<string to remove>=%`

For your case,

```
set FFNAME=%FDATE:-=%%FTIME::=%
set FFNAME=%FFNAME:Z=%
```

yeilds the string

```
20180123131211
```

See this reference for more details.
https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: …just beat you to the punch, although I used a slightly different method of dropping the `Z`!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! But I still have an issue: I use for /f to get %%i as 2018-01-23 and %%j as 13:12:11Z. I can use %%i on my java command line. But when I use "SET FDATE=%%i" and "SET FTIME=%%j", I cannot use %FDATE% or %FTIME% in my java tools. So how can I get rid ":" in %%j? Thanks.

Comment: @DBALUKEHUANG, my reply was quicker!

Comment: @Compo easy questions get answered so fast... I actually saw the notification about your answer right when I was scrolling down to hit "Post"